# router.push() doesn't reload router-view in VUE

Tags: vue.js, push, vue-router, reload

I have simple auth system for my selfhosted app. After pass valid username and password i need to redirect router-view.

Unfortunately, when I call `router.push("/")`, there is nothing happen.
Then I have to click "login" again or manualy reload page or use `router.go()`.

I can not reload all page after login, I need to update only `router-view`.

I searched many issues but there are no answer for me.

Do you have any idea, what's wrong ?

```js
//router.rs
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import LoginPage from "../views/LoginPage.vue";

Vue.use(Router);

export const router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [{
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: LoginPage
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      name: "about",
      component: () => import("../views/About.vue")
    },
    {
      path: "*",
      redirect: "/"
    }
  ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const publicPages = ["/login"];
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem("user");

  if (authRequired && !loggedIn) {
    next("/login");
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

```js
// fragment of LoginPage.vue
import { userService } from "../services";
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      submitted: false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    loggingIn() {
      // return this.$store.state.authentication.status.loggingIn;
    },
    alert() {
      return this.$store.state.alert;
    }
  },
  created() {
    // reset login status
    userService.logout();
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit() {
      this.submitted = true;
      if (this.username && this.password) {
        userService.login(this.username, this.password).then(
          ok => {
            this.$router.push({ path: "/" }, () => {});
          },
          e => {
            console.log(e);
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: what happens if you just do `router.push('/');`

Comment: There is no `url` option for the `location` argument. You want `{ path: '/' }` (if you insist on using an object). See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort

Comment: when i use `router.push('/');` then nothing happens and a have to refresh browser..  `url` is my thought in this example, using `path` doesn't change anything.

Comment: I think that the problem may be in `router.beforeEach()` ... see updated question above. when I remove this function, `push` works ok

Comment: Can you post rest of the route.js file, if the code works on commenting out the `beforeEach()` then clearly there is some issue in the file.

Comment: OK few pointers, 1) Do not use `router.push()` from Vuex store. It is better to return the promise and allow the component method to call it. I am not sure how you getting access to direct `router` instance from vuex anyway. 2) Instead of using a `publicPages` array you can use the `meta: { }` property for route navigation which is recommended by router https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html

It's also better to call `router.push({ name: 'login' }) than the path, this way if you decide to re arrange your urls, you don't need to change the routes everywhere

Comment: thanks I'm going to try do this that, now I have to rewrite component and auth module to retrun Promise...

Comment: I update src code in question. Please check it. My problem always exist...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thing:
[Here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) we can find implementation of `beforeEach` and i used them. And it does't solve my problem.

I moved last `next()` form else to the ond of labmda and it works.

```js
// fragmet from docs
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (...) {
    // this was unnecessary for this explanation
  } else {
    next() // make sure to always call next()!
  }
})
```

```js
// fragmet from my code
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (...) {
    // this was unnecessary for this explanation
  }
  // I removed `else` node for last `next()` call
  next() // make sure to always call next()!
})
```

Anyway, please tell me why it doesn't worke when `next`is in `else` ...